# basic program output redirect not working in CentOS V. 2.16.0 release 5.8

Tags: linux, shell, redirect, centos, csh

Generally `>` or `>&` both work when I am redirecting output from a program that is run from a C Shell script, but these are not working for basic output redirection to a log file in CentOS v.2.16.0 release 5.8 (final) Gnome desktop.

When I try to redirect program output to a text/log file using `>` or `>&` within my C shell script, I come up with an empty (blank) log file. Is there some kind of buffering going on, or why isn't this working when I use it in my C Shell script?

For the record, `>&` does work fine on the command prompt/ console, but then the same exact syntax does not work within my C Shell script. Any solutions? I have tried `cat`, `tee`, `1>&`, `2>&1` and every variation of output redirection thereof, but nothing gets the program output into my text log file within my C Shell script.

(Please, no lectures on "why are you using C Shell".)

Comment: Can you post a) The first line of your C shell script (are you sure it is running as a C shell?) and b) the full command where you are doing the i/o redirection.

Comment: @Brad Lanam`#!/bin/csh`  The command looks something like program inputvar1 input var2 input var3 >& output.log

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I had to make it work by separating both

```
ls / 2> /dev/null 1> /dev/null
```

To test that this is working I echo the exit code.

```
ls /dir/doesnt/exisst 2> /dev/null 1> /dev/null && echo $0
ls / 2> /dev/null 1> /dev/null && echo $0
```